# Can't reset rotation of object

Tags: objects, edit-mode, transforms

I am following a tutorial to learn Blender and I have a rotation problem.

All the rotation values of my object are reset to 0 but it is still rotated. Apparently rotations made in Edit mode apply differently but I am now unabled to reset it to zero.

I tried ctrl + R and Clear all user tranformations and nothing seems to work.

Thanks

Comment: if you've rotated your object in Edit mode, you won't be able to get back to the original rotation position (well actually you can but you will have to use some complex tricks). If you reset the rotation to zero with alt R it will only reset the rotations you've made in Object mode. And also, if you've applied the rotation in Object mode with ctrl A, you also wont be able to reset (again, except with some tricks).

Comment: I would like to know about the tricks. Or how to avoid it next time.

Comment: How to avoid it: if you want your object (cube for example) to remain orthogonal to the grid, don't rotate it in Edit mode, only rotate it in Object mode, and don't apply the rotation. This way you'll always be able to go back to the original position with a simple alt R. About the trick: I'll try to find it.

Comment: here is the trick: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0pfTDzAaXp4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** It's now easier **since 2.8** as you can enable the *Affect Only > Origins* in the *Options* and use it to realign to a custom orientation.

**Previous versions:**

If you've rotated your object in *Edit* mode, you will only be able to get back to the original rotation position with a trick like the one I'll explain below. In *Object* mode, if you reset the rotation to zero with <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> it will only reset the rotations you've made in *Object* mode, not the one you've made in *Edit* mode. And also, if you've applied the rotation in *Object* mode with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>, you also won't be able to reset (again, except with the trick like the one below).

**How to avoid it:** if you want your object (cube for example) to remain orthogonal to the grid, don't rotate it in *Edit* mode, only rotate it in *Object* mode, and don't apply the rotation with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>. This way you'll always be able to go back to the original position with a simple <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>.

**Now, the trick to align a randomly rotated object (cube for example) to the grid**

as explained by refa42 in a youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0pfTDzAaXp4

[image]

Comment: In short.. freeze the mesh by  hooking it, allowing you to transform the object (axes) _any way you like_  without transforming the mesh associated with it. I can't believe I haven't come across this complete replacement for the _transform pivot point_ function in other applications before. Other methods are so complicated  / arbitrary / non-general by comparison with this one.

Comment: I don't even remember how this one works, this is the kind of tricks that gives me headache, fortunately we don't often need this kind of operation...  :)