# How to reset the axis of mesh rotated in edit mode?

Tags: modeling

I did a lot of looking around and I cannot seem to find a simple method to reset to default rotation the axis of a mesh that got rotated while in edit mode. Clearing rotation in object mode no problem with Alt+R. But how to do that in edit mode? I want the cube to stay as it is in object mode where it's location and rotation is kind of randomized, just so it's perhaps not as easy to align anything to global orientation. So with the cube remaining in it's object mode location and rotation, how can I reset it's local axis back to it's default rotation as in picture 1 below? Picture 2 below is the cube having been rotated in edit mode. Is there a simple method I'm overlooking, or does it involve a bit of a step by step longer process to "reset" the mesh axis in edit mode? I would like to to know how to realign the axis back to it's "default" state in this cube mesh. Thanks for any ideas.
Blender 2.80
Windows 10

[image]

Blender_2.80_edit_mode_before_changing_default_rotation_of_cube
[image: my note, text here does not show up on page]

Blender_2.80_edit_mode_after_changing_default_rotation_of_cube
[image: my note, text here does not show up on page]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/121227/15543  .

Comment: When you make a rotation in object mode, you just change the rotation property, which can be reset to 0. When you rotate an obect in edit mode, you move vertices, so you change the location of each vertex - WITHOUT keeping the old location. So technically speaking, you can't reset the rotation in your case - you can only rotate the vertices again in such way that the cube looks as before the initial rotation. Still, vertex IDs might not match. The solution might be easy for a cube and impossible for some arbitrary shapes, where it's not apparent what orientation it had initially.

Answer (score 1):

You may Snap Faces in object mode which can cause a rotation.

You may create an Orientation. And Transform the orientation.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gc8BekthXAQ

There are also add-ons. You will still have to do some work. Probably scripts exist as well.  I can make no statements about 2.8.

Once the axis is reset, you need to select two faces source and destination.  Then you have the freedom to select location in the orientation and rotation along z-axis of local transform orientation.  The requirement of artistic/technical freedom requires some small amount of work from the Blender User.

You can make changes in edit mode, then go to object mode, then enter edit mode and undo those changes with the typical keystrokes of <kbd>Control-Z</kbd>.  I suggest you test it because I would use that feature rarely.  I would not perform hundreds of useful things and then undo in edit mode.

Comment: I need other than undo because this may be a rotation created in an earlier project for example, where I want to go back to the project and do some editing. Regarding snapping faces, I don't know how to use that to reset this cube's axis in edit mode. Thanks.

Comment: Okay I found a solution here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119120/cant-reset-rotation-of-object but is this still the only way to "reset" the rotation of a mesh that has been rotated in edit mode? Or is there a simpler way in Blender 2.80 perhaps? Thanks for any other ideas.

Comment: The video link probably has a more complete display of the concept than other items I have seen here.  Good Luck.  Please downvote or upvote the small bit of information.

Comment: @frew .. I'm gobsmacked, after all this time,  not to have come across this before :) Thank you. IMO, the method shown by moonboots in your link is a complete solution to transforming the pivot point of an object any way you like, without  transforming its mesh. A 'reset' would require a memory of the way a mesh was related to the object axes on creation.. but which part of the mesh? All mesh elements can be transformed independently of one another, so there's nothing to lock on to.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger, thanks for the link to the video tutorial, that has some useful tips too. I have very limited scripting abilities at this time, but those ideas may be helpful too at some point as I learn how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: @Robin, you're welcome. Thank you too for the explanation of why the mesh itself cannot be "reset", thus no way to clear it's rotation in edit mode. I'm really excited about this technique using hook modifier to hold the mesh in place while I rotate the axis of the mesh back to 0s with Alt+R. If I understand correctly, that's what appears to be happening.

Comment: Whoops, I meant use the hook modifier to hold the mesh in place while I rotate the axis of the mesh back into alignment using Object> Transform> Align to Transform Orientation. Then after my goal here is achieved with that, then Alt+R in object mode to zero out the rotation of the object if I wish to. I add this comment for others new to this. I think this is how it works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This won't change the orientation of the object but will allow modification on the global axis at least.

In *Edit Mode*, press the axis letter twice.

For example: <kbd>S</kbd> (scale) <kbd>X</kbd> (x axis) <kbd>X</kbd> (local x axis).

Also, hotkey <kbd>,</kbd> (comma) can set the orientation of the transform axes: *Global,* *Local,* *Normal*.

Comment: Welcome to BSE! And thanks for taking the time to post your first answer. Although, it isn't readily apparent how exactly this will help realign an object that has been rotated in edit mode. Consider making a short gif [(helpful software)](https://www.screentogif.com/) or screenshot(s) to show how this can fix the orientation and edit your post to include it.