# I'm having problem with adjusting the pivot of an Object

Tags: snapping

How to translate or rotate Pivot of an object and keeps the pivot in the adjusted direction, please help if anybody knows about this.

Comment: .. Recommend the answer relayed by @moonboots [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/119123/35559).. allowing you to transform the pivot without transforming the mesh.

Answer (score 1):

The pivot point of an object is its origin: you can set the origin where you want: a common procedure is to select a vertex (or a group of vertices) where you want the pivot to be, then press Shift S - "Cursor to selected", then in object mode select the object and choose the option "Origin to 3D cursor".

[image]