# Keep mesh rotation but reset rotation value to 0

Tags: transforms

This question has been [asked and answered here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/119123/83475).  However the solution is for an older version of Blender and the description for the newer one is too terse for me to apply it.  Could someone elaborate on how to:

> enable the Affect Only > Origins in the Options and use it to realign to a custom orientation.

I have found the Options > Affect Only > Origins, but it still seems to rotate the object as normal which does not let me remove the previously applied erroneous rotation to the object (which for tidiness I would like to remove).

[image]

Comment: Select your object and CTRL-A > rotation?

Comment: Yes, brilliant.  Thanks!  There are so many "hidden" blender menu shortcuts I still need to learn :D
Please post as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Now done. The most frequently used one from that menu is to reset the scale and I assumed everyone knew that one because it's used so often! :^)

Comment: Brilliant.  Well I really am a beginner and I still don't know what to search for to find that answer out for myself!  xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select your object and <kbd>CTRL - A</kbd> > <kbd>Rotation</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

John Eason's answer is correct: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> → **Rotation**

To expand on the reasoning behind this, the **A** in the shortcut stands for "**apply**". When you apply a transformation (**Location**, **Rotation**, or **Scale**), the transformation becomes part of the object's data in its native state (when Loc/Rot/Scale are all set to `0`).

An exception to this is a Curve object whose Shape is set to **2D**... for such an object only Scale can be applied, unless you switch it to 3D.